# add Y axis labels to D3 bar from json data name attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i was following the  [Let's make a Bar chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) tutorial and have run into an issue...in step three He rotates the bars to columns, and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to iterate over a json data set, and add Y-axis labels for each bars from the name attribute in the json data returned

Here is the jsfiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/7K3tt

and the code samples below
the json data loaded

```
[
    {
        "name": "1-30 days",
        "value": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "31-60 days",
        "value": "14"
    },
    {
        "name": "61-90 days",
        "value": "1"
    }
]
```

My D3 code

```
var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);


d3.json("<?=APP_PATH?>/query", function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);


  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  You want to rotate what you have so far, keeping the labels at the top of each bar?

Comment: no i want the name attribute to be displayed next to the bar along the y axis, like this http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bar-hierarchy.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [d3 axis labeling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189284/d3-axis-labeling)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189284/d3-axis-labeling, as I am asking how to iterate over a result set and add labels dynamically, not statically...i updated my question to be more clear on my intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by rotating the bars to columns, but all you have to do to achieve what you want is to add another set of `text` elements using the existing selection:

```
bar.append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("dx", "-1em")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7K3tt/2/). I've also shifted the bars to allow space for the new labels.

Comment: You have clipped last bar, here is how it should be - http://jsfiddle.net/7K3tt/3/

Comment: Thank you, perfect...now did you learn this by the documentation? not sure where i should be to improve my D3 knowledge

Comment: Have a look at the tutorials. Ultimately, you just need to get the experience by working with it.